# angular-google-maps - listen for infowindow domready event

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, infowindow, angular-google-maps, domready

Listening for the domready event in normal js Google maps is relatively easy
as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5505179/3092596) :

```
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
      // whatever you want to do once the DOM is ready
});
```

However it doesn't seem obvious how to do it in [angular-google-maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps).

Is there a solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution when using [Angular Google Maps](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps) involves using the infowindow control object - [see docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/window).

As noted in [this issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-google-maps/issues/1584) - where I first posted this solution - you can create an empty infowindow control object within the main controller :

```
$scope.infowindowControl = {};
```

Then you scope bind your new object in the `ui-gmap-window` directive definition like :

```
<ui-gmap-window
    options="windowOptions"
    closeClick="closeClick()"
    control="infowindowControl"
>
```

On infowindow open (actually unsure at what point) - it will pass five functions to the empty object you created within $scope. Some of these functions are noted in the [documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/window) but in a rather haphazard and non-defined way :

- getChildWindows()
- getGWindows()
- getPlurals()
- hideWindow()
- showWindow()

The one that you need is `getGWindows()` - which you put inside your marker `click` event.
This will get you an *array* of the open infowindows and you can now attach an event listener in the standard google maps fashion, like :

```
var windows = $scope.infowindowControl.getGWindows();
    console.log('inside click after getGWindows ', windows);
google.maps.event.addListener(windows[0], 'domready', function() {
    console.log('infowindow domready just fired !!');
});
```

While it's not an ideal, well documented or easy solution (and took me a number of hours to figure out) - and passing functions to an empty object is frankly counter-intuitive - it does seem to work.

[Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WIfDF8CQ0sGJFF1DJ6PH?p=preview).